# where is my error in finding total derivative of function, chain rule.

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

I am going over my high school calculus and I can't find my mistake.

Given function $f\left(  x,y\left(  x\right)  \right)  =xy+\frac{1}{y}$ and I
wanted to take its total derivative w.r.t. to $x$, i.e. $\frac{df}{dx}$, so
I used chain rule (notice that $y$ is function of $x$)

\begin{align}
\frac{df}{dx}  & =\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dx}+\frac{\partial
f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx}\nonumber\\
& =\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}
{dx}\tag{1}
\end{align}

Is the above correct so far? Now $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is the
partial derivative of $xy+\frac{1}{y}$ w.r.t. $x$ which is
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=y+x\frac{dy}{dx}\tag{2}
\end{equation}
and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ is partial derivative of $xy+\frac{1}
{y}\ $w.r.t. $y$ which is
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=x-\frac{1}{y^{2}}\tag{3}
\end{equation}

So far ok? Now the problem comes in when substituting (2,3) back into (1)
which gives

\begin{align}
\frac{df}{dx}  & =\left(  y+x\frac{dy}{dx}\right)  +\left(  x-\frac{1}{y^{2}
}\right)  \frac{dy}{dx}\nonumber\\
& =y+2x\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{1}{y^{2}}\frac{dy}{dx}\tag{4}
\end{align}

But the above is wrong. The final result should be just $\frac{df}
{dx}=y+x\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{1}{y^{2}}\frac{dy}{dx}$. This is seen by doing the
following instead of the above

\begin{align}
\frac{df}{dx}  & =\frac{d}{dx}\left(  xy+\frac{1}{y}\right)  \nonumber\\
& =\frac{d}{dx}\left(  xy\right)  +\frac{d}{dx}\left(  \frac{1}{y}\right)
\nonumber\\
& =y+x\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{1}{y^{2}}\frac{dy}{dx}\tag{5}
\end{align}

Comparing 4,5 shows they are not the same. Where is my error in using the
formula (1)? Why using (1) gives an extra term $x\frac{dy}{dx}$?

Comment: (2) is incorrect. You need to consider $y$ as constant to $x$, so that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = y$.